# Adding a Advanced Custom Field to Woocommerce users My Account Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am using **admin columns** together with **ACF (advanced custom fields)**
in the backend I created a field in ACF for just some text, now with admin columns I made this field viewable in the backend for me to add some text that I want .

Now I want to display this text in the my-account page on the frontend.
now I got this far that i added the snippet code to the account page and that works .

But it's only displaying the DEFAULT value I have filled in in ACF and not the value I have entered in the admin custom column backend.

so to clarify even more in my users backend page i give the user a string of text.
That text needs to be displayed in the frontend on the users account

So all users should have a different string of text. The text I can add using admin columns
thats no problem but its only displaying (echo,printing) this text that I have filled in there to the woocommerce account page is not working.

Again I only get the default result text from ACF there not the text I had put in.

For getting default message the code that I use now is:

```
<?php echo the_field('ethwallet'); ?>
```

This is giving me the default message right now. not the result that I entered in the backend.

Comment: oke thanks i will change that. but still only the default value is returned and not the users backend one.

Comment: oke so i got a little further it seems that i need to get a USER ID to display the right value now i found this piece of code for wordpress to get the user id . 

function get_current_user_id() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) )
        return 0;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return ( isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 0 );
}

now i need to blend this in with this piece of code but how  

<?php get_field('ethwallet', 'user_123'); // where 123 is the user ID ?>

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question, but I wanted to provide an answer as it has been viewed several hundred times.

To retrieve custom meta data (specifically ACF field data) from a User object you need to pass in the current user ID as a second parameter to the `get_field` or `the_field` function.

Like so:

```
<?php echo get_field( 'ethwallet', 'user_' . get_current_user_id() ); ?>
```

The way it works is that ACF needs the second parameter formatted as `user_X`, where `X` is the actual ID of the user (1, 347, whatever). So we concatenate the string part ('user_') with the actual ID of the logged in user and that forms the full parameter to pass to `the_field()` or `get_field()`.

P.S. It's a minor detail, but in this case `echo the_field();` is redundant because `the_field()` echoes its values by default. You could likely omit the `echo` or do `echo get_field();`